# Error when get value in from node father?

Tags: mysql

I have a sample data:

```
product(id, parent_id, name)
        1 |  0  | Windows
        2 |  1  | XP
        3 |  1  | 7
manufacturer(id, parent_id, name)
        1 |  0  | Westwood Studios
        2 |  1  | Red Alert 1
        3 |  1  | Red Alert 2
product_manufacturer(product_id, manufacturer_id)
        2 |  2  
        3 |  2
        3 |  3
```

And mysql:

```
SELECT prod.name
FROM `manufacturer` AS child
INNER JOIN `manufacturer` AS parent ON parent.id=child.parent_id 
INNER JOIN `product_manufacturer` AS pr_ma ON pr_ma.manufacturer_id=child.manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN `product` AS prod ON pr_ma.product_id=prod.product_id 
WHERE parent.id=1
GROUP BY prod.id
```

When `parent.id=1 (manufacturer=Westwood Studios)` is result is `XP, 7`

How to fix when `parent.id=1` is result is `Windows`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT prodparent.name
FROM `manufacturer` AS child
INNER JOIN `manufacturer` AS parent ON parent.id=child.parent_id 
INNER JOIN `product_manufacturer` AS pr_ma ON pr_ma.manufacturer_id=child.manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN `product` AS prod ON pr_ma.product_id=prod.product_id 
INNER JOIN product AS prodparent ON prod.parent_id=prodparent.id
WHERE parent.id=1
GROUP BY prod.id
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen Rieck, I find this problem